# Is Internet Explorer 6 mobile upgradable on Windows Mobile 6.5 platform?

Tags: windows-mobile, internet-explorer-6, upgrade, windows-mobile-6.5, ie-mobile

I have to support Windows Mobile 6.5, and it comes with Internet Explorer Mobile 6.

I did some research and found that Internet Explorer Mobile 6 is essentially Internet Explorer 6 ([IE Mobile 6 breakdown](http://www.networkworld.com/news/2008/121908-microsoft-mobile.html?page=1)).

Is IE Mobile 6 upgradable?  Can I upgrade it to IE Mobile 7 on Windows Mobile 6.5?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.  It's baked into ROM and cannot be upgraded (well not without upgrading the entire OS, which only the device OEM can provide).